# How to use jquery variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in which there is criterion to apply different class. For example if in loop i is odd then .odd-product is applied to the div and if i is even then .even-product is applied to the div.

Here it is:

```
<div id="product"<?php if($i%2==0){?>class="even-product"<?php } else {?>class="odd-product"<?php } ?>>
```

Now I reference that div in the following way in jQuery:

```
    $divClass=$('#product').attr("class");
```

Now I want to hide a div whose class name is contained in $divClass variable. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You would just use it like a string:

```
  $divClass=$('#product').attr("class");
  $("." + $divClass).hide();
```

Comment: why $ is used here @J Torres rether then var.

Comment: OP named his variable "$divClass".  I don't agree with it, I just went with it.

Comment: It's good practice to name jQuery object variables with the `$` to indicate that those variables are, in fact, jQuery objects. The `$` does not affect the behavior of the variable in any way.

Comment: Right, but `$('#product').attr("class")` isn't a jQuery object, it's a string.